# EXCEL VBA keep changing variables and creating ppt apresentation by interval

Tags: vba, excel, loops, if-statement, replace

Browsing I didnt find nothing especific as I need indeed.

The code I'm looking for, uses "AG6" and "AK6".
AG6 is my client (44 clients) and ak6 my product (4 products).

as a loop, for AG6 = 1 and ak6 = 1 it'll create a power point presentation pasting a certain range [A1:T35], and so on. AG6 still 1 while ak6 <= 4, and everytime ak6 changes it'll create the presentation. when ak6 reaches 4, ag6 goes to 2 and when ak6 reaches 4, ag6 +1 again until 44.

I tried to be more clear I could. I've already done the ppt code but i'm stuck on that loop.

Thank you in advance !! 
see ya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? I'm not sure from your title whether your problem is with the looping code or with invoking PowerPoint - what does "use replace code" mean? Anyway, here's a simple nested loop  - the "Debug" line is just to show that the loop actually works.

```
Sub testloop()
Dim client As Integer
Dim product As Integer
With ActiveSheet
    For client = 1 To 44
        .Range("AG6") = client
        For product = 1 To 4
            .Range("AK6") = product
            'Do Something Here
            Debug.Print .Range("AG6") & " - " & .Range("AK6")
        Next product
    Next client
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake when I was writing another question, forget it !

Exemple:

1

```
. client as 1 and prod as 1
    client as 1 and prod as 2
    client as 1 and prod as 3
    client as 1 and prod as 4
```

when prod reaches 4, client goes to 2 and do the same thing.

between every time prod variable changes, i'll create the ppt apresentation.